# Change Flutter local notification icon background color

Tags: flutter, user-interface, notifications

Hey guys i was wondering how i could change the background color/accent color of the local notification icon. i know for changing firebase messaging icon background we use this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
              android:resource="@color/background_color" />
```

but i couldn't find any thing for flutter local notifications, it's always grey. any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You can change icon color by specifying color in the NotificationDetails. But make sure the icon is monochrome and has a transparent background.

```
NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails('id', 'name', 'des',
          // Specify the color
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),

          importance: Importance.max),
      iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
    );
```

Comment: I want black color, but it shows grey while using black color. how to use black color

Comment: Where we put this code?

Comment: @AntonioKomangYudistira Put it last param on method flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show.  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Answer (score 2):

Convert all parts of the image that you don’t want to show to transparent pixels. All colors and non transparent pixels are displayed in white

Comment: I don’t wanna make it white. I wanna make it red like the above code “background” is red

Comment: The notification icon without any transparency will be in white colour. Make an icon with some transparency.